# DalSoft WebApi HelpPages Sample Generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have taken to using the DalSoft.WebApi.HelpPages nuget package to generate a website to document my api for some internal API test tools. Its great, but I cannot figure out how to use the "Sample" section of the site.

Looking at the code I have no idea how it actually inteprets, nor what it inteprets.

I have tried adding `<example>..</example>` comments to the code, but it doesn't appear in the help pages. It would be a great feature if I could get it working as endpoints that take `post`/`put`/`delete` actions would be able to have an example/expected JSON object on the api help.

The github site for DalSoft Helppages is here: https://github.com/DalSoft/DalSoft.WebApi.HelpPage I did raise an issue on there to try figure this out, but havent had a response in ~5 months.

Comment: I am note aware of DalSoft so wouldn't be able to help there. But as per your requirements, how about using [`Swashbuckle`](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) instead? It will generate swagger help page for your app which you can use not just for documentation but also for testing it out. It includes support for OAuth as well.

Comment: @degant thanks, will have a look. Did like the DalSoft tool as it just worked after enabling xml and adding IAppBuilder middleware. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Give it a shot, instructions on the github page. Setting it up is the easiest! I have it enabled for quite a few Web API projects.